# Kotlinx Coroutines - Integrate with legacy Lamda Syntax

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

Consider the following 3rd party function, which I can't refactor:

```
fun doSomethingAsyncWithLamdas(completion: (Throwable?) -> Unit) {...}
```

What's the proper way to invoke (and wait on) this lamda-centric function from a suspend function?

> Note: I'm using Kotlin Multiplatform's Kotlinx Coroutines, not sure if an answer might depend on that.

---

Best I could come up with is using a Mutex:

```
suspend fun waitForBlock(block: ((Throwable?) -> Unit) -> Unit) {
    val mutex = Mutex(locked = true)
    block { throwable ->
        throwable?.let { throw it }
        mutex.unlock()
    }
    // Wait for the unlock
    mutex.lock()
}
```

Usage example:

```
suspend fun myAwesomeSuspendFunc() {
    // Do stuff

    waitForBlock { completion -> 
        doSomethingAsyncWithLamdas { exception ->
            completion(exception)
        }
    }

    // Do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you're looking for is a way to wrap a callback-based API into a `suspend` function that's suitable for coroutines.

The function you're looking for exists and it's called [suspendCancellableCoroutine](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html).

You can use it this way:

```kotlin
// assuming this is given
fun doSomethingAsyncWithLambdas(completion: (Throwable?) -> Unit) {...}

// you can declare this
suspend fun mySuspendWrapper(): Unit = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    doSomethingAsyncWithLambdas { th ->
        if (th == null) {
            cont.resume(Unit)
        } else {
            cont.resumeWithException(th)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  I couldn't find it for the life of me, hopefully your answer will help others in their search as well.  Thank you!